# Fatal error: Call to a member function build_tree() on null in ... vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php on line 580

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I tried integrating `"dompdf/dompdf": "^0.7.0"`in my app, I am literally, trying it out using their example:

```
$app->pdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$app->pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$app->pdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$app->pdf->stream();
```

and yet I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function build_tree() on null in xxx\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php on line 580

They do not have documentation for setting up, am I missing something? Hope somebody can help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you include autoloader ? and declare namespace like exemple provided => https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: @Fky yes I did, and just based from the error, it is calling the Dompdf lib files just fine?

Comment: did you install with composer ?

Comment: @Fky yes I did, `composer require dompdf/dompdf`

Comment: I think for some reason $app->pdf->loadHtml('hello world') it's null.